# Same Identity Id for different Users in Cognito User Pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, swift4

I have created two Users (from XCode simulator) in Cognito userPool as seen in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkDMr.png)

Then, i was looking forward Identity browser in Federated Identities, to assign different unique identity id's for each user. Unfortunately, there is only one identity id and two different accounts are using the same data (in dataset)  like in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTe1G.png). I have also done same method mentioned in the question below. But still i have an issue.

[Integrating Congnito User Pools with Amazon Cognito Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37491909/integrating-congnito-user-pools-with-amazon-cognito-identity)

My code in App delegate;

```
let serviceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: nil)

// create pool configuration
let poolConfiguration = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration(clientId: "2xXx6X77x7X8YYyyy7X9",
                                                                        clientSecret: "f87as68a7f68adf6sa897f79af789a7fda8a7sd698",
                                                                        poolId: "us-east-1_XXXXXXXX")

// initialize user pool client
AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.register(with: serviceConfiguration, userPoolConfiguration: poolConfiguration, forKey: "UserPool")

// fetch the user pool client we initialized in above step
let pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(forKey: "UserPool")
self.storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
pool.delegate = self

//SAVE & LOAD DATA TO AWS COGNITO SYNC
let credentialProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast1, identityPoolId: "us-east-1:xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx", identityProviderManager: pool)
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialProvider)

//credentialProvider.clearCredentials()


AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
```

I have tried to add `credentialProvider.clearCredentials()` into App delegate and signOut function, but both does not help to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out the following and see if it fixes your issue:

- Call [`credentialsProvider.clearKeychain()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider.html#//api/name/clearKeychain). This clears all saved values - credentials & IdentityId. Use assert to check if IdentityId is cleared `assert(credentialsProvider.identityId == nil)`
- Before making Sync calls, get an identity id using `credentialsProvider.getIdentityId()`.
- How are you signing your user out? Try using the signout() method

  ```
  let user = pool?.currentUser()    
  user?.signOut()
  ```
- The SDK remembers the last known user by default. Use `pool?.clearLastKnownUser()` to clear it, if required.
- Call [wipe()](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-ios/blob/4234924f418c83c4db1c905d2eedc088ba0677f0/Cognito/AWSCognitoService.h#L318) method of Cognito sync client to wipe cached data

Comment: My signout() method is as follows; `func signOut() {
        let credentialProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast1, identityPoolId: "us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0", identityProviderManager: pool)
        credentialProvider.clearCredentials()
        self.user?.signOut()
        self.title = nil
        self.response = nil
        self.collectionHome.reloadData()
        self.refresh()
    }`

Comment: When i signed with 2nd account with an another device(in simulator), it created a 2nd identity id for it. Now, My current issue is, when i sign with 1st account, app is loading its dataset, after i sign out and sign in with 2nd account, still its loading its previous(1st account's dataset) data. Here, if before signing with 2nd account, i have relaunch the app and then i sign with 2nd account, its loading its data set succesfully

Comment: Looks like idenity id or some sync constructs are being cached. Does clearKeychain clear the id (check using assert)? So, even after above calls (wipe, clearKeychain etc.) it still uses the old id? Or is it that the id is new but it is showing cached sync data?

Comment: "when i sign with 1st account, app is loading its dataset, after i sign out and sign in with 2nd account, still its loading its previous(1st account's dataset) data" - Try printing the IdentityId in this case & see which one is being used

Comment: you are right,  i have added credentialProvider.clearKeychain() and         credentialProvider.clearCredentials() to my signOut() method. Moreover, to my appdelegate i have added print(credentialProvider.identityId). After i signed out and relaunch the app, identity id has still value (1st account's id because i have signed out from it)

Comment: So identity id is being cached. Try setting it to nil on signout

Comment: Yes, i have finally succeeded to make it nil (with `DispatchQueue.main.async {
            credentialProvider.clearKeychain()
            assert(credentialProvider.identityId == nil)
            credentialProvider.clearCredentials()
        })` 2nd account is opening with his own identity id and 1st is own too, But still when loading data set, 2nd is loading the 1st's dataset

Comment: my load method is; `static func loadDefaults() { dataset.synchronize().continueWith {(task: AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in if (task.error == nil) {
   let json = dataset.string(forKey: "bulbs")
   print(json!)
    bulbs = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Bulb].self, from:(json?.data(using: .utf8))!)
   //print(bulbs)
   print("loaded from AWS Cognito")
   NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "reloadDataAndView"), object: nil, userInfo: ["Cell": "reloadView"])
   } else {
  //initDefaults()
 print("ERROR HANDLED = initDefaults loading")
  }
  return nil
  }
}

Comment: Did u call the wipe method on sync client?

Comment: its DONE :), i have added AWSCognito.default().wipe() inside signOut() method, it works well right now, thanks much.. I have one more question, for ex if cognito user is deleted (or removed), how its identity id and its dataset removed automatically? Because, when i delete one user aws cognito console, his identity id and dataset is still there..Thanks again

Comment: It won't be deleted automatically. Userpools & IdentityPools are completely separate & independent. For example, if you add Google as an OIDC provider in your Id pool & create an IdentityId & if the google user's account is deleted, it won't affect cognito id, right? Of course, without a valid token you won't be able to use that id

Comment: I have got it, if some user is deleted from cognito, i am planning to delete his identity id and dataset manually (by lambda function) otherwise, there can be too many unused datasets.